# Get DateTime from mongo collection using c# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have the following object:

```
public class QueueItem
{
    public long _id { get; set; }
    public SiteMapRequestState State { get; set; }
    public int WorkerId { get; set; }
    public DateTime QueuedTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartWorkTime { get; set; }
}
```

When I save the object to mongo the date appear right (the DateTime fields contains the correct date that I inserted). However when i pull this object I get different time (-3 hours).

For example:
I save the object with StartWorkTime = 6/26/2012 **10:00:00 AM**, then when getting the object from the collection StartWorkTime equals to 6/26/2012 **7:00:00 AM**.
This make the calculation of process time wrong.

I'm using the latest c# driver (1.4.2.4500) and running both code and the mongo server on the same machine.

What can cause the difference?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After digging a bit i found this posts:
http://alexmg.com/post/2011/09/30/DateTime-precision-with-MongoDB-and-the-C-Driver.aspx

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial#CSharpDriverSerializationTutorial-DateTimeSerializationOptions

I needed to mark the DateTime property with [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)] attribute

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue once.  Be sure to also specify the DateTimeKind parameter to DateTimeKind.Utc

Hope that helped.